# not able to acces this file in flutter android Included build 'C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android' does not exist

Tags: flutter

Included build 'C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android' does not exist.
give me the solution for this why i am unable to access this location or why that android file is not generation automatically

i tried to solve this but there is no solution for this